# How to make sure that when you click on one of the arrows, you go to the next or previous section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make it so that when you click on one of the arrows, the transition to the section above or the section below occurs?
I am not very good at javascript and I am just starting the path of a web developer and therefore I am asking for help. Thanks in advance

Site http://ct03638.tmweb.ru

Code jsfiddle.net/5oukrxtL/

[image]

```html
<nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#main" class="dot active" data-scroll="main">
                        <span>Главная</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about_us" class="dot" data-scroll="about_us">
                        <span>О нас</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services" class="dot" data-scroll="services">
                        <span>Услуги</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#sequence" class="dot" data-scroll="sequence">
                        <span>Порядок работы</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#stages" class="dot" data-scroll="stages">
                        <span>Этапы работы</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#portfolio" class="dot" data-scroll="portfolio">
                        <span>Портфолио</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#news" class="dot" data-scroll="news">
                        <span>Новости</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contacts" class="dot" data-scroll="contacts">
                        <span>Контакты</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is kinda hackish, but it works.
Don't forget to add appropriate classes to your arrows `arrow next`, `arrow prev`.

```js
$('.arrow').on('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const direction = e.target.parentNode.classList[1]
  const $dotToClick = $('.dot.active').parent()[direction]().find('a').get(0)
  if ($dotToClick) $dotToClick.click()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a4u3fw6v/2/

Comment: Thanks It works! I have a question - why if the names of the arrows change to "up" or "down" instead of "prev" and "next" then the code does not work? Indeed, in the code itself there are no references to "prev" and "next"

Comment: And another question - is it possible to do this using the scrollHeight, Window.scroll, Element.scrollTo, etc.

Comment: Yeah it relies on `prev`, `next` class names. The `direction` variable is equal to either prev, or next, jQuery also has such methods, same function name - prev/next, and I utilize either prev, or next in square brackets, depending on what arrow button you clicked. `e.target.parentNode.classList[1]` = give me the second class name of the button that user clicked. If you really need up/down instead here is another fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z07qds2h/

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you want. I think other solutions will require more code, or refactoring.

Comment: did I understand the logic of the code correctly?

1) When clicking on an element with class .arrow, an event occurs
2) in the variable 'arrowClassNames' I make settings that the property 'up' is bound to the element with the class 'prev'
and 'down' binds to an element with class 'next'

Comment: 3) the variable "direction" contains the second class of the parent of the element that was clicked,
since the first class is "arrow" and is counted from 0.
4) const $dotToClick = $('.dot.active').parent([arrowClassNames[direction]]().find('a').get(0)if ($dotToClick) $dotToClick.click()
in this line, I understand only part of the code and cannot understand its logical chain.

Comment: another question: in the line const arrowClassNames = {up: 'prev', down: 'next'} a constructor or an array is enclosed in a variable? Or what is the correct name for {up: 'prev', down: 'next'}?

Comment: That's an object, object literal.

Comment: `next/prev` is not an element, it is one of the jQuery methods, that's why we need square brackets around the direction variable, cause you call a method dynamically it is either prev, or next. `next/prev` selects next, or previous HTML element, in your case it is one of the li's with `a.dot` inside. https://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: When you click an arrow, it triggers a click to one of the `dot`s previous or next from `.dot.active`, so you basically click one of the `dot`s when you click an arrow.